# Laravel multiple orderBy()

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code.

```
$array= $this->morphMany
('App\Models\Asset', 'assigned', 'assigned_type', 'assigned_to')
->withTrashed()  
->orderByRaw('LENGTH(name)', 'ASC')->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
```

I am using it to perform a natural search on a string with alphanumeric characters, as using an alphabetic search causes strange ordering e.g.
product1
product10
product2
product20

It seems to be working flawlessly.

I have a few questions about this, mainly what is the algorithm used in orderBy? and how does the combination of both here end up giving me a natural order? I get that the combination of a length check and alphabetic check is the solution, but how does this work in laravel? is there a specific sort algorithm used here such as merge sort? I don't understand how it prioritizes one sort over the other.

I'm a total newbie to laravel. Thanks.

Comment: I have no morphed Table so I tested it on my User Model with  
 User::orderByRaw('LENGTH(name)')->orderBy('name')->get()   and it works fine. Could you post an example of your expected result?

Comment: Hi. My sort is working fine, I was just asking about the theory behind the sort, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: `item123` would come before `item2` in the dictionary. To overcome this you're saying "Sort according to the dictionary only when the items have the same length otherwise shorter items come first". By that combination of rules you get:

- `item2` comes before `item11` because it's shorter (`ORDER BY LENGTH(name)` takes priority)
- `item123` comes before `item234` because it precedes it in the dictionary (Items have the same length so they are ordered by their value)

Now what algorithms MySQL uses for sorting are not important, but it's enough to know that it's optimised for speed and sorting data for huge data sets. What is important is that each sort algorithm uses a `compare` function to compare two values and determine their order.

MySQL constructs this function based on your `ORDER BY` statements and its own internal comparison rules. For example: `ORDER BY LENGTH(name), name` could result in a comparison as follows:

```
compare(x,y) 
     if (default_comparer(LENGTH(x.name),LENGTH(y.name)) == 0) { 
         return default_comparer(x.name,y.name);
     } else {
         return default_comparer(LENGTH(x.name),LENGTH(y.name));
     }
```

where `default_comparer` would be a mock name of the default internal comparers that MySQL uses which (in the case of strings) would take a number of things into account like alphabetical order, locale, case rules etc. (In reality MySQL probably has a general comparer and then iterates through each order by statement to get the first non-zero result to return).

This are all a bit vague, I'm not a MySQL developer so I can't provide more precise information, but this is the rough image of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Laravel, your database decides how ordering is done.

Normally, when there are two or more `ORDER` statements, the results are first ordered by the first statement. If there are elements that have the same value for the first order statement, these are ordered by the second order statement and so on.